# Power saving circuit in pneumatic valve

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, low-power, solenoid

I am looking for a pneumatic valve and I refereed a catalog. It has a power saving circuit in the valve and there is a circuit diagram and description of that.

I couldn't understand how this power saving circuit works. Below is the description about that as the catalog.

[image: Power saving circuit]

Can someone explain about function and how it saves power ?

This is the full [catalog](http://ca01.smcworld.com/catalog/New-products-en/mpv/es11-113-jsy-np/data/es11-113-jsy-np.pdf). ( See page 44 for above description)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The valve works by attracting an iron armature into a solenoid. This means that when un-energised, there's a large airgap in the magnetic circuit. When it's energised, the airgap is much smaller.

The large initial airgap means that a large current is required to develop enough force to move the armature. When the airgap is smaller, less current is needed to develop the same force.

The power saving circuit appears to be integrated into the valve. When you apply power to the valve from your control, the timer circuit turns the transistor on, which applies the full voltage across the valve coil. After a while, during which it's assumed that the valve has pulled in, the timer circuit turns the transistor off, and the coil is now only supplied through the resistor. This lowers the voltage to the coil, causing it to draw less current, but still enough to hold the valve on.

This is a quite inefficient method of doing it. Had they used a buck converter instead of the resistor, then the power consumption could be reduced yet further, albeit at a higher cost for components.

Comment: Pretty clear.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just so the poor guy knows what a buck converter is. A buck converter reduces the power by switching the transistor on & off rapidly instead of using a resistor. The inductance of the coil resists changes in the current by generating a reverse voltage which keeps the current flowing through the diode (known as a freewheel diode) across the coil. All the necessary power handling components are already there. I don't know why they didn't use that method. All they needed to add to the timer is a cheap little IC like an LM555 timer.
Buck converters are normally part of a low voltage switchmode power supply (say 12V to 5V for a phone in your car), using a transistor, switched with variable width pulses and an inductor to smooth it out. Because the transistor is only on part of the time, the average input current is less than the output current, which is supplied the rest of the time by the inductor, like the current generated by the valve coil.